# Mapbox map loading crash

Tags: dictionary, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

This is the error message shown from React Native app with mapbox GL JS that my dev team works on:

ERROR  Mapbox error MapLoad error Failed to load tile: Unknown exception type {"level": "error", "message": "MapLoad error Failed to load tile: Unknown exception type"}

Also, I am also encountering same crash with mapbox studio preview IOS version.

Interestingly, I duplicated the style and removed layers for my own debugging. However, after removing all layers, still there is crash with even no layer at all.

Successful Map loading